# Everytime records are edited condition in Process Builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder

[image]I have a requirement in which when I choose account type as client and any related contact's account name is changed,we want to send email alerts to the contact owner.

I tried to build using process builder since workflows would not support cross objects but the process builder only triggers when new records are created and the email is received.When I change the account name from an existing one to a different one,I donot receive the email alert.

There isn't any option in process builder to have the criteria Evaluate the criteria as 'created, and every time it’s edited' like in workflow. If I try using workflow,I am not able to choose the value for Account Name is Changed like in process builder.In workflows I get the options Account name is changed.

Please let me know how can I get the emails alert for the condition when the records are edited everytime in process builder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see my screenshot below.   you'll need to select the Object in your process to toggle this option, and will need to save as a new version.

[image]

Comment: Hi James thanks, When I create a new record,I get the email alert but when I change the account owner form previous to a new value, I donot get the  email alert.

Comment: I tried to create a workflow which says: (Account: Type EQUALS Client) AND (Contact: Account Name EQUALS ISCHANGED (Account.Name )) still I donot get the email alert. What condition should I put in workflows?

Comment: What are you rule criteria?   I suspect the logic is not capturing the change.  Also, what are your steps to changing Account Owner (Using the the "Change Owner" button?

Comment: Sounds like you need an OR in your logic    ISCHANGED (Account.OwnerId)

Comment: James,Let me explain you from the scratch. When I change the Account name field on contact object and my account type field on account object is client,the contact owner should get an intimation regarding change of account name.I have attached the screenshot..

Comment: Can you share (post screenshot) of your flow?  It will be helpful to include the criteria as well.

Comment: I am trying to add the formulae in the workflow  mentioned below: AND( ISCHANGED (Account.Name),OR( Account.Type = 'Client')) but it shows the error as Error: The ISCHANGED function cannot reference the Account.Name field.The account name is a lookup value. Can you suggest me a formulae?

Comment: Please, post the screenshot.   Also, The way I understand your question is:   When a Contact record's Contact.AccountId value is changed AND the Contact.Account.Type is 'Client'  THEN email the Contact.OwnerId.     Please confirm, or re-write your question since it is not clear.

Comment: I am trying to add the formulae in the workflow mentioned below:

AND( ISCHANGED (Account.Name),OR( ( Account.Type  =  'Client'))) 
but it shows the error as Error:

The ISCHANGED function cannot reference the Account.Name field
Basically I trying to do here is when I change the account name field on contact and account type field on account is client,the contact owner should get an email alert.

The account name is a lookup value here.

Comment: There's a lot more infromation a screenshot provides, and I feel like I'm taking shots in the dark at this point.     We don't even know which Object this Flow is running on, which will completely change the answers received.     My last suggestion on this (based on what I stated above to be your scenario) is to us ISCHANGED (AccountId).

Comment: Hi James,I apologize,where can I find the place to attach the screenshot?

Comment: edit your original question and you should have an option for importing an image.

Comment: James I have added the image,further can you please suggest me a formulae at least so that I can put that formulae in workflows:

Comment: Thanks.  Also what is your master Object in this flow (my screenshot shows "Appointment", so what is it in yours?           You should change the "Run this rule when : Criteria are Met" to "When Fomula Evaluates to TRUE"   Here, you can use the ISCHANGED() function.

Comment: My master object in this Case is contact

Comment: Awesome, then ISCHANGED (AccountId) should work fine.

Comment: Thanks James the formulae did not show any error :AND( ISCHANGED (AccountId),OR(ISPICKVAL(Account.Type, "Client") )) but I did not receive the email alert :(

Comment: Did you make the change in my screenshot, save your formula, activate the new Flow, and then go to contact record and change the Value in the Account field where the current Contact.Account.Type = "Client"?      If not, I recommend starting simpler and only test the process with the formula "ISCHANGED (AccountId)", then build from there.

Comment: @kunalgupta, great news!  Please be sure to mark as answer.